# What exactly "W" do in unpack function in Perl?

Tags: perl, unpack

I couldn't understand what exactly "W" do.

```
my $x = "this is my string";

print unpack("W",substr($x,0,1));
```

Prints: 116

```
my $x = "this is my string";

print unpack("W",$x);
```

Still Prints: 116

Comment: Subham, all of your answers re: perl functions lie behind one command: 'perldoc perlfunc' - reading that whole perldoc is highly recommended; taught me a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html): `W  An unsigned char value (can be greater than 255).`

Both of your examples return the same thing because your unpack argument `"W"` only consumes one character. Try `"W*"` instead.

Comment: Yeah. You are right but why 116? ASCII value of "t" aint that.

Comment: `ord 't' == 116` and `The ASCII code for capital T is 84 and for lowercase t is 116` - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T

Comment: Shubham: `man ascii` works on any unix system. It's the fastest way of checking hex/octal/decimal values of ascii characters.